# Teaser trouble with Views block

Tags: views, nodes

I have a content type of blog that I created a view for and added a display of that view. I created a view block and have it displaying on the front page in the main content block. I decided that I would rather display the blog posts as a teaser instead of the full text but I can't seem to get it to work.

I set up the content type as a teaser under manage display. Should I be able to select the blog teaser as a content type separate from the default blog display under filter criteria in views? Essentially how do I go about setting the content type blog, within my views block to display teasers instead of the full content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set views to output as Show: Content | Teaser

Then in your content type > manage display, click the teaser display mode tab, then set the body field to 'Summary or Trimmed'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! every tutorial with teasers leaves that out apparently.